# Regular Expression Extractor on JMeter doesn't work properly

Tags: jmeter

I think I have an issue on JMeter.
Consider the following scenario :

```
Controller
    User defined variables (I define here a variable named var="12345")
    Regular Expression Extractor (in which I define a new variable var2 which will contain the 4 first characters of var, so var2="1234")
    BeanShell Sampler (I've just put log.info("my var2 is " + vars.get("var2"))
```

The expected result is to print the value of var2. Unfortunately, I got null instead of "1234".
If I put a "Debug Sampler" just after the "Regular Expression Extractor", it works fine.
Is there something I've missed ?

Comment: Can you please post what is in your extractor configuration?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use Regular Expression Extractor to extract first 4 digits from a User Defined Variable, apply the following configuration:

- Apply to: Jmeter Variable - `var`
- Reference Name: `var2`
- Regular Expression: `(\d\d\d\d)`
- Tempalte: `$1$`

Also make sure that you add Regular Expression Extractor **after or (better) as a child** of a sampler as it it a [PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors), and if the PostProcessor doesn't have parent or preceding sampler - it just won't work at all.

[image: Regex]

Above configuration should work fine.

See [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide for advanced information on extracting data using regular expressions in JMeter.